# MapKit zoom button

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

My question is about a map service I'm using a map with custom tile service now I need to add two buttons or a stepper to zoom in and zoom out and I'm using MapKit library. can someone help with that?

Comment: I have answer but in objective c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out answer

```
switch sender.tag {
    case 10:
    //Zoom In

        var region: MKCoordinateRegion = map_view.region
        region.span.latitudeDelta /= 2.0
        region.span.longitudeDelta /= 2.0
        map_view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    case 20:

   //Zoom Out
        var region: MKCoordinateRegion = map_view.region
        region.span.latitudeDelta = min(region.span.latitudeDelta * 2.0, 180.0)
        region.span.longitudeDelta = min(region.span.longitudeDelta * 2.0, 180.0)
        map_view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thnx dude simple and easy for my problem

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the answer in swift 3**

for zoom In

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.region.center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta*0.7, mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta*0.7))
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

for zoom out

```
   let zoom = getZoom() // to get the value of zoom of your map.
   if zoom > 3.5{ // **here i have used the condition that avoid the mapview to zoom less then 3.5 to avoid crash.**

            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.region.center, MKCoordinateSpanMake(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta/0.7, mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta/0.7))
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
```

Here you can get the how much the map view is zoomed.

```
func getZoom() -> Double {

    var angleCamera = self.mapView.camera.heading
    if angleCamera > 270 {
        angleCamera = 360 - angleCamera
    } else if angleCamera > 90 {
        angleCamera = fabs(angleCamera - 180)
    }
    let angleRad = Double.pi * angleCamera / 180
    let width = Double(self.view.frame.size.width)
    let height = Double(self.view.frame.size.height)
    let heightOffset : Double = 20
    let spanStraight = width * self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / (width * cos(angleRad) + (height - heightOffset) * sin(angleRad))
    return log2(360 * ((width / 256) / spanStraight)) + 1;
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thnx dude it works too